# using when...else statment in port map

Tags: vhdl, fpga

i can't find anything about using when...else statment in port map. It seems to be a correct form but when i compile i see a error like this :

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Device.vhd(68) near text "when"; 
>   expecting ")", or ","

It's probably a silly mistake cause i'm still fresh in vhdl. Could you give me a hint about this? I would be very thankful for any help.
Here is the code and the SDA port is inout type:

```
com : I2C_com port map (

             reset_en => reset_en,
             I2C_clock_port => SCL,
             clk => clk,
             sda_read_data <= SDA when RD ='1' else 'Z',
             sda_write_data => SDA 
        );
```

Comment: Use an intermediate signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one, your arrow points in the wrong direction. For port associations, always use `=>`, regardless of input or output ports.

Second: the when/else construct is not an expression like `a?x:y` is in C. It is specific to a when/else signal assignment: http://www.sigasi.com/content/signal-assignments-vhdl-withselect-whenelse-and-case

You need to either use an intermediate signal, or use an adaptor function:

```
com : I2C_com port map(
        reset_en       => reset_en,
        I2C_clock_port => SCL,
        clk            => clk,
        sda_read_data  => SDA_or_z,
        sda_write_data => SDA
    );
SDA_or_z <= SDA when RD = '1' else 'Z';
```

or:

```
com : I2C_com port map(
        reset_en       => reset_en,
        I2C_clock_port => SCL,
        clk            => clk,
        sda_read_data  => myFunction(SDA,RD),
        sda_write_data => SDA
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one signal temp<= SDA when RD='1' else 'Z';
then assign sda_read_data <= temp;